# ASP.NET w/ Identity: Entity Framework throws System.Data.Entity.Core.UpdateException on SaveChanges

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I am trying to build an ASP.NET application which should facilitate carpooling.
For it, I use the Identity Framework to manage accounts and Entity Framework as ORM. I use the ApplicationDbContext of Identity for my models too, so I won't have problems with the code-first migrations and because I need a one-to-one relation between a UserProfile object and the Identity's ApplicationUser.

Here are my models:

```
public class UserProfile
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        public virtual List<Trip> Trips { get; set; } = new List<Trip>();
        public virtual List<Meeting> Meetings { get; set; } = new List<Meeting>();
    }
```

---

```
public class Trip
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public virtual TripCheckpoint Departure { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public virtual TripCheckpoint Destination { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int Seats { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public int AvailableSeats => Seats - Passengers.Count;
    [Required]
    public virtual UserProfile Organizer { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; } = 0.0;
    public virtual List<UserProfile> Passengers { get; } = new List<UserProfile>();
    public virtual DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
public class TripCheckpoint
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int CheckPointId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Place { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public TimeSpan Hour { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
public class Meeting
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime When { get; set; }
    public string Where { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my ApplicationDbContext:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public DbSet<UserProfile> Profiles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Trip> Trips { get; set; }
    public DbSet<TripCheckpoint> Checkpoints { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Meeting> Meetings { get; set; }

    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("helmoCars", throwIfV1Schema:false)
    {

    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder dbBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(dbBuilder);
        dbBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().HasRequired(u => u.Profile).WithRequiredPrincipal().Map(m => m.MapKey("AppUser_Id"));
        dbBuilder.Entity<Trip>().HasMany(t => t.Passengers).WithMany().Map(m =>
        {
            m.ToTable("Trip_Passengers");
            m.MapLeftKey("Trip_Id");
            m.MapRightKey("UserProfile_Id");
        });
        dbBuilder.Entity<Trip>().HasRequired(t => t.Organizer).WithMany(u => u.Trips).Map(m => m.MapKey("Trip_Organizer"))
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
        dbBuilder.Entity<Trip>().HasRequired(t => t.Departure).WithRequiredDependent().Map(m => m.MapKey("Trip_Departure")).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
        dbBuilder.Entity<Trip>().HasRequired(t => t.Destination).WithRequiredDependent().Map(m => m.MapKey("Trip_Destination")).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

    }
}
```

This is how I use my ApplicationDbContext:

```
public class TripRepository
{
    private ApplicationDbContext _db;

    public TripRepository(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        this._db = context;
    }

    public void AddTrips(List<Trip> trips)
    {
        _db.Database.Log = message => Debug.Write(message);
        _db.Trips.AddRange(trips);
        _db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

I use my TripRepository like this:

```
ApplicationDbContext context = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationDbContext>();
var tr = new TripRepository(context);
tr.AddTrips(trips); // trips is a valid List<Trip>
```

The SaveChanges() method of the ApplicationDbContext throws a System.Data.Entity.Core.UpdateException each time I call it, even if I'm sure the trips that I add to the DbSet is a valid List, I checked it with the debugger.
The exception is the only feedback I have, so I really don't know what I'm doing wrong here.. Any ideas?

This is the only feedback I get in the debug output window:

```
Exception levée : 'System.Data.Entity.Core.UpdateException' dans 
EntityFramework.dll
Exception levée : 'System.Data.Entity.Core.UpdateException' dans 
EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll
Exception levée : 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException' dans 
EntityFramework.dll
Exception levée : 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException' dans 
System.Web.Mvc.dll
Exception levée : 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException' dans 
System.Web.Mvc.dll
```

This is how I fill the List that I give to the AddTrips method afterwards (where trip is a viewmodel that I get from a form):

```
trips.Add(new Trip()
                {
                    Date = trip.Date,
                    Price = trip.Price,
                    Seats = trip.Seats,
                    Organizer = user,
                    Departure = new TripCheckpoint() { Place = trip.DeparturePlace, Hour = trip.DepartureHour.TimeOfDay },
                    Destination = new TripCheckpoint() { Place = trip.DestinationPlace, Hour = trip.DestinationHour.TimeOfDay }
                });
```

Comment: did u used EF or EF Core?

Comment: InnerException with details?

Comment: I use EF (not EF Core).
I have nothing more specific than "System.Data.Entity.Core.UpdateException"

Comment: The `Trip` class contains a lot of navigation properties. If all they are disconnected entities, adding trip to the context will mark all them as new, hence the `SaveChanges` will try to insert new records, which most likely is not your intent. Btw, the exception either directly or inside inner exception should contain more information what operation failed. Also the Debug window should show the commands.

Comment: I don't think my entities are disconnected, I just added to the post how I build those. I have also added the result I get in the output.

Comment: You can [log](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn469464(v=vs.113).aspx) the attempt to help diagnose what's wrong.

Comment: I resolved it, it was a FK problem between the Trips and TripCheckpoints. The fact that my feedback was so poor was because I was working with AJAX so I only saw what came in the Debug output in Visual Studio while the feedback that you generally receive on the view is way more complete. So if anyone has the same problem, I would suggest you to firstly try it with a simple html form, and once it work turn it to an ajax form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found better logs in the view (I was working with AJAX). For other people having the problem, if you want better logs to find the error, try it with a html form and turn it into an ajax form once it works.